# Restarting applications with shutdown.exe

Tags: windows, system-shutdown

According to the help for `shutdown.exe`, the `/g` switch does the following

```
/g         Full shutdown and restart the computer. After the system is
               rebooted, restart any registered applications.
```

I noticed that when I use this switch, not all the applications in use prior to the system shutdown are restarted.

So my question is this: is there a limit to the number of applications that can be restarted or is it that I don't understand the meaning of the term **'registered'**? I suspect the latter to be case and would appreciate some guidance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`/g` will restart any application that registered itself with the [RegisterApplicationRestart API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/winbase/nf-winbase-registerapplicationrestart) **UNLESS** the application was forcefully terminated. So, if you don't allow enough time `/t` for the application to gracefully save and close, it will not restart.

Comment: Thanks for this explanation. How long is "long enough" ? Is there a way to track which application failed to register?

Comment: I thought I read somewhere that the minimum is 60 seconds while the maximum time Windows will allow an application to gracefully exit is...5 minutes?? I'm sure there's a way to poke around and find which applications aren't registered, but it would be far easier to use a script to run shutdown.exe and get a list of running applications before the restart then re-open them after the restart.